# PEP8: `is True` vs `is None`

Tags: python, coding-style, styling, pep8

[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) have a strong opinion about boolean comparison:

> Don't compare boolean values to True or False using ==:
>
> #### Correct:
>
> `if greeting:`
>
> #### Wrong:
>
> `if greeting == True:`
>
> #### Worse:
>
> `if greeting is True:`

But when talking about `None`, which is also a builtin singleton, the recommendation is:

> Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with is or is not, never the equality operators.

So why checking if `x is True` is worse than checking if `x == True` when it comes to boolean values?

Comment: A bit of discussion about it: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/python-ideas/EWj5ciqkaO0/ENEWg5BY1DIJ

Answer (score 0):

"is" tests identity and doesn't compare like "==". Usually you want to compare, this is why "is" is "usually worse" than "==", but "is" isn't "wrong" at all. It just depends on the purpose.

Comment: Thanks, but rhat doesn't answer the question: why `is True` is actually worse than `== True`?

Comment: Don't change afterwards: You're  question actually was about `is True` vs `is None`.